# Check whether it is deleting last row with specified value in column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dataset

I have a button that deletes rows from a DataGrid; one of the columns is the admin column. I need the program to check whether the row (or rows, since it can delete multiple rows) that is being deleted is the last one with Admin = true, since deleting the last administrator renders this table unaccessible.

The code for deleting rows is this:

```
connection.Open();
List<DataRow> theRows = new List<DataRow>();
for (int i = 0; i < funcDataGrid.SelectedItems.Count; ++i)
{
    Object o = funcDataGrid.SelectedItems[i];
    if (o != CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder)
    {
        DataRowView r = (DataRowView)o;
        theRows.Add(r.Row);
    }
}
foreach (DataRow r in theRows)
{
    string a = r.Field<string>("usernameFunc");
    cmdSel = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM usersFunc WHERE usernameFunc='" 
        + a + "'", connection);
    cmdSel.ExecuteNonQuery();

    int k = ds.Tables["funcionarios"].Rows.IndexOf(r);
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[k].Delete();
}

connection.Close();
```

Keep in mind it's deleting from two joined tables, so I couldn't delete rows the usual way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a variable (static or not, depending on how you implemented your class) called `ActiveAdmins`. Upon loading of your Datagrid, you could easily query your DB and get the number of admins.
I'll assume you have a boolean column `IsAdmin` on your objects.

in your `foreach` loop, add something like:

```
if (r.Field<string>("IsAdmin"))
  if (`ActiveAdmins` <= 1)
      continue;
```

This way, whenever you're deleting, if it's the last admin stading, it'll just go to the next row, leaving your last admin in the table.

Comment: Just implemented this successfully! Thank you very much for the tip. I thank you for the title correction, too; I had it almost exactly like that before, but thought it would be easier to understand that way, turns out it wasn't.

Comment: Hahaha, looked at my location, did you? xD

Comment: ;) was torn between that and "de nada", because of your `funcionarios`. So yep, a quick look solved that for me ...